# How to make the default Wordpress search return borader results

Tags: wp-query, search

I'm displaying the results of a search query on one of my custom pages. The query is simple:

```
$shopArgs = array(
    's' =>   get_query_var('s'),
    'post_type' =>  'products',
    'posts_per_page'    => 3,
);

$shopQuery = new WP_Query($shopArgs); 
..
```

If I have a `products` post entry titled "Carousel Watch", but my search (`s`) parameter is "Carousel Watch Gift", I will not get any results. The search for either "Carousel" or "Gift" will yeld results.

How can I refine these searches so that Wordpress returns broader results so that a search for ""Carousel Watch Gift" will return at least "Carousel Watch". What is the way to go here?

I will only add that due to the site's architecture, I'm not able to use plugins such as "Revelanssi", so I'm looking for a 'native' solution.

Comment: What is `var_dump($shopQuery);`? That does not look like untwitched search results to me.

Comment: What you want should already be how WP behaves by default. There is a 'exact' parameter that WP_Query accepts and it is set to "false" if you don't change it. As @s_ha_dum suggests, please let us have a look at your $shopQuery. Perhaps a 3rd party plugin is changing your final SQL-query.

Comment: @s_ha_dum This is the output of `var_dump($shopQuery)` - http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/287462/bc435218257a775d2370de27b6b9b075   Passing `'exact' => 0` also does not help

Comment: That sequence of `LIKE` clauses looks right but I am pretty sure that `CASE` statement is not native. Have you tried without plugins and using a default theme?

Comment: @s_ha_dum the `CASE` does not have any bearing on what is returned. It only determins the ordering of the found items and. I inspected the whole query (obviously it's shortened in the screenshot)

Comment: I know what the `CASE` statement does! I mentioned it because it isn't Core so something is messing with the query. The `LIKE` clause with wildcards should be doing what you want. Something else is causing trouble for you, either in the query (Is there a `HAVING` clause?) or after.